# set and get thread or global value throughout server requests

Tags: python, django, http, request, web.py

Is it possible to set a thread or something alike to store a value among each server request?

I understand that values from threads or globals are get/set only during each server request, also this values cannot be changed out of context because everything is done inside "mapped" classes.

Eventhough I am just being curious out of this because it would be great to set a value and manipulate it over each request, I don't know it may be a variable stored in memory so that it may be referenced later.

I am saying this because sessions, cookies and everthing related to a web application is manipulated only through each GET/POST request. o far this is what I have:

```
import web
import threading


threadlocal = threading.local()

def set_value():
    setattr(threadlocal, 'mythread', 'threadvalue')


def get_value():
    return getattr(threadlocal, 'mythread', None)




urls = (
    "/set_thread_value", "set_thread_value",
    "/get_thread_value", "get_thread_value"
)


app = web.application(urls, globals())



t_globals = {
    'template_thread': get_value()
}    
render = web.template.render('templates', globals=t_globals)



class set_thread_value:
    def GET(self):

        set_value()

        return get_value()




class get_thread_value:
    def GET(self):

        return get_value()
```

As you can see when you call "set_thread_value" you set the thread value and it is displayed on screen, but when you call "get_thread_value" you will get None instead.

You may also have noticed that I want to pass the thread to a template so that it can be displayed with its updated value.

Edit:I don't want to use mysql, mongodb or any other storing system to set the value from the thread.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware application is normally hosted on many threads? What you want to do is plain wrong. What is your use case excatly?

Comment: I want to set that value so that it can be displayed on the template, I have found something that aproaches to what I want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6688459/1747721

Comment: Use memcache or something similar - that's what it's there for

Comment: Hey @TimmyO'Mahony you are right man with memcache I can store the value and keep on memory so I can use it later, how can I choose your answer?

Answer (score 3):

You should user something like [memcache](http://memcached.org/) (or [redis](http://redis.io/)) to store content and values which you need to persist in memory across requests. Here's a related question regarding globals:

[Python Django Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680902/python-django-global-variables)

Comment: Yeah, this is the best way to store the global state. Because app might be deployed in separate processes.