# How to save variable value of the last session(program exit)

Tags: java

How can i save the value of a variable in my program and then reuse it at the next program run ? I don't want to do it with file write/read.

Comment: "*I don't want to do it with file write/read*" can we know the reason for this? Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `don't want to do it with file write/read` use database? But why do you want to do this?

Comment: Related: [Keep persistent variables in memory between runs of Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687660/keep-persistent-variables-in-memory-between-runs-of-python-script)

Comment: I don't know , thats why i am asking .. i don't want it to be modified easly

Comment: In "*then reuse it at the next program run*" do you mean other app, or also the same app (like after restarting it)?

Comment: Same app, after restarting it .

Comment: What exactly do you mean "modified easily"?  If you're just worried about access, you can always encrypt the data when you persist it.

Comment: Yes, i am talking about the acces to it.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify your problem then.  I think @Pshemo hit it on the head that this is an XY problem.  It sounds like what you want to know is how to persist data for reuse the next time your program runs, such that nothing but your program and read and/or alter that data.  This has nothing to do with *where* you persist your data (i.e. in a file).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Java Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html).

```
import java.util.prefs.*;

public class Example {
    // Preference key
    private static final String FRUIT = "fruit";

    public void savePreference(String favoriteFruit) {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(Example.class);

        prefs.put(FRUIT, favoriteFruit);
    }

    public String readPreference() {
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(Example.class);

        return prefs.get(FRUIT, "default");
    }
}
```

The data is stored based on the fully-qualified name of your class, so your package name and class name are relevant. From the [documentation for the Preferences class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html):

> This class allows applications to store and retrieve user and system preference and configuration data. This data is stored persistently in an implementation-dependent backing store. Typical implementations include flat files, OS-specific registries, directory servers and SQL databases. The user of this class needn't be concerned with details of the backing store.

Answer (score 1):

One can store settings using [java.util.prefs.Preferences](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPreferences/article.html). For two target groups: normally user settings, and less often application/system settings. They can use the platform settings, like under Windows.

There exists however also the possibility to store the settings as XML, which is a cleaner way, as it does not touch the Windows registry, which might be protected. Then a customary location would be inside a directory like ".myapp" under the directory `System.getProperty("user.home")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an in-memory key-value store like [Redis](http://redis.io/), or an in-memory database like [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html).  But this may be overkill depending on your needs.

Comment: Interesting idea, but will it also work when we restart our machine (just asking since I never used these tools and this case seems to be quite important)?

Comment: How would an in-memory database survive a restart?

Comment: @Pshemo it will not, since you are only writing it to memory and the memory will be erased when you restart the machine. However, you could host Redis on a different server that doesn't restart and write to that.

Comment: @JBNizet That is what I meant. But I assume that maybe it has mechanism which on restarts store data on disk and when machine is starting reads it to memory and deletes from disk.