# Load a dataframe to memory python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large file I need to load to a dataframe. I will need to work on it for a while. Is there a way of keeping in loaded in memory, so that if my script fails, I will not need to load it again ?

Comment: Maybe you can [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) it using [`to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#pickling)

Comment: And maybe [this](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization/) help.

Comment: Thanks ! How about other data structures ? like numpy matrices or objects ?

Comment: numpy is easy `pd.DataFrame(numpyarray)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687660/keep-persistent-variables-in-memory-between-runs-of-python-script) of how one can keep variables in memory between runs.

For persistent storage beyond RAM, I would recommend looking into `HDF5`. It's fast, simple, and allows for queries if necessary: [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables).

It supports `.read_hdf()` and `.to_hdf()` similar to the `_csv()` methods, but is significantly faster.

A simple illustration of storage and retrieval including query (from the docs) would be:

```
df = DataFrame(dict(A=list(range(5)), B=list(range(5))))
df.to_hdf('store_tl.h5','table', append=True)
read_hdf('store_tl.h5', 'table', where = ['index>2'])
```