# Need a variable to retain it's value when the script is executed again (Python)

Tags: python, environment-variables

Currently I'm working on tweepy and I need to store tweet id in a variable and want it to retain this value when the script is made to run again. I know I can do this using files and db but I want to do it using environment variable. Looking for a nudge in the right direction.  I have set the environment variable from the terminal using the command >export en=1
  Here is the code that I'm using :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import tweepy 
import time
import random
import os
t=time.time()

#my api keys 
consumer_key = "xxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"
access_key = "xxx"
access_secret = "xxx"


toReply="xxx"
rt=['hello','hi','okay','bye']
#rt=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','you','suck','bruh',':P']
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
ts=api.user_timeline(screen_name=toReply,count=1)
#g=open('id.txt','r')
#x=g.read()
#g.close()
x=os.environ["en"]
print x
l=[]
#print dir(ts)
#print ts.max_id
#print type(ts.max_id)
def unique(y,l):
    for i in range(0,len(l)):
        if l[i]==y:
            return 0
if int(x)!=ts.max_id:        
    for tweet in ts:
        for i in range(0,len(rt)+1):
            y=random.choice(rt)
            #print y
            if(unique(y,l)!=0):
                    #print("unique")
                    api.update_status("@" + toReply + " "+y, in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id)
                    #print y
                    l.append(y)

    os.environ["en"]=str(ts.max_id)
    print os.environ["en"]
    '''
    f=open('id.txt','w')
    f.write(str(ts.max_id))
    f.close()
    ''' 
t1=time.time()-t
print t1
```

Comment: Environment variables are one directional:  they go from the command interpreter (or other execution environment) into a program.  They are also  inherited by descendants of the process.  But a program cannot alter its parent's environment.

Comment: I suggest you do use a file, `pickle` it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep persistent variables in memory between runs of Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687660/keep-persistent-variables-in-memory-between-runs-of-python-script)

Answer (score 1):

Pickle is suggested in a comment, but it has the large drawback that you cannot edit a pickle from outside a the Python program.

If you want something like a Windows .ini file, then the Python library module you want is ConfigParser as per this answer [How to read and write INI file with Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884188/how-to-read-and-write-ini-file-with-python)

Another possibility is to use JSON (module `json`). This can be extremely complex, but if you stick to a single dictionary of key:value pairs it isn't.

Yet another possibility is YAML.

In all cases you may also want `atexit` to register an exit handler so that the state of your configuration variables will get saved whenever the program exits sensibly.