# list clears when i end my app and re run it

Tags: python, list

How can I define a list that is empty at first and append to it but not have it clear when I restart my app? I am using python language

The list has the proper values in it when the app is first ran, it is only when I restart my app that the list clears because of the empty list variable over rides the list that was just created. Thanks in advance

Comment: i am using the python language

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever your variables would be magically saved and loaded. Take some time to learn the basics. Then implement save and load features should you need them.

Comment: could i save a dictionary with that list in it to a file  and get the values back that way?

Comment: Possible starting point: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep persistent variables in memory between runs of Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687660/keep-persistent-variables-in-memory-between-runs-of-python-script)

Answer (score 1):

A list doesn’t get saved when closing a python program. If you want this you should save the list in a specific file and load this file everytime your python program opens. One of the basics of python is that lists, dictionairies etc don’t get saved on change or exit.