# i want to save the responses i get from users through my code so how do i do that

Tags: python

this is my code and i need a way to store the input i get from the 'a' variable

```
print("Hey Welcome To Mental health chatbot")
import time
time.sleep(1)
a = input("So how are you felling today ").strip().upper()
if (a == "NICE") or (a == "GOOD") or (a == "I am good"):
    print("That's nice to hear")
if (a == "BAD") or (a == "NOT NICE") or (a == "IT WAS A BAD DAY"):
    print("Oh")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "store"? You're already storing it in variable `a`.

Comment: Store it where?  You have it stored, in memory, as `a`.  Where else do you want it?

Comment: Side notes: you spelled "feeling" wrong. Also, you convert to upper case but then compare to "I am good" which has lower case letters,

Comment: if i rerun the code then then the variable 'a' will get reset

Comment: Have a look at [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to save to disk. Or just [`write`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) `a` to a file.

Comment: so by using prickle the input i get from the users will get saved even when i rerun it

Comment: You need to store the info in some persistent manner. Writing to a file on disk is one way.

Comment: Is this the whole program, or is this inside a function inside a bigger program?

Comment: its a part of a program

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687660/keep-persistent-variables-in-memory-between-runs-of-python-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to store the value in a file like that :

```
def storeVar(a) :
   f = open("filename.txt", "w+") # w+ allow to write and create the file if it doesnt exist
   f.write(a)
   f.close() #always close a file as soon as you stop using it

def readVar() :
   f = open("filename.txt", "r")
   a=f.read()
   f.close()
   return(a)
```