# Examples of rewrite rule engine in Python?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, logic-programming

Are there any existing projects within the Python ecosystem that use [rewrite/production/transformation rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_%28computer_science%29) in way similar to Mathematica or Maude?

Note that I'm referring to the logic programming concept, not the web server concept.

Comment: use search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917607/relational-logic-programming-in-python