# what is the best data structure to represent prolog facts and rules bases in python

Tags: python, data-structures, prolog

i'm looking for the best data structure to represent prolog facts and rules bases in python for easy manipulation later , for example :

```
    parent(abraham,ismael).
    parent(abraham,isaac).
    parent(isaac,iacob).
    grandfather(B,N):- parent(B,P),parent(P,N).
```

is it the nested list like this :

```
base=[["parent","abraham","ismael"],["parent","abraham","isaac"],["parent","isaac","iacob"]]
```

or with dictionary :

```
base={"parent": ("abraham","ismael") ,"parent": ("abraham","isaac"), "parent":("isaac","iacob") }
```

or is there any best methods of representation that you suggest in this case .

PS: i mean by best : simplest , easiest , flexible way .

Comment: Sorry but this is off-topic as it's opinion-based as you're asking for best. Really you should just use what works until it doesn't work. Saying that this is similar to a network so you may consider networkx which supports these kinds of relationships

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917607/relational-logic-programming-in-python

Comment: Define `'best'` (c: Algorithms and data structures go hand-in-hand. Do you mean the simplest, or most efficient, most flexible, extensible. What do you need to achieve with the data structure? Is it just defining the grandparent relationship?

Comment: @languitar i'm not looking for libraries , i have to implement it all by myself

Comment: @EdChum i don't think so

Comment: @PeterWood i mean by best : simplest and easiest and flexible one ; and for the link that you gived to me : i'm not looking for libraries i have to implement it all by myself

Comment: See [PyKE](http://pyke.sourceforge.net/), in particular [this example](http://pyke.sourceforge.net/examples.html#family-relations)

Comment: @PeterWood i will it's what i'm looking for , and thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use python-like literal dict syntax directly in prolog.

## Solution

```
{
    'parent':
    {
        'name_of_parent': 'abraham' ,
        'name_of_child': 'isaac'
    }
}
.

{
    'parent':
    {
        'name_of_parent': 'isaac'   ,
        'name_of_child': 'iacob'
    }
}
.

{
    'grandfather':
    {
        'name_of_grandfather':  __B__   ,
        'name_of_grandchild':   __N__
    }
}
:-
(
    {
        'parent':
        {
            'name_of_parent': __B__ ,
            'name_of_child': __P__
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        'parent':
        {
            'name_of_parent': __P__ ,
            'name_of_child': __N__
        }
    }
)
.
```

## Example Query

```
?- 
{
    'grandfather':
    {
        'name_of_grandfather':  __B__ ,
        'name_of_grandchild':   __N__
    }
}
.
__B__ = abraham,
__N__ = iacob ;
false.
```

## Caveat

The `:` operator might not be defined automatically for your implementation of prolog .  If you get a syntax error because of the `:` , then place this at the top of your file:

```
:-  op((10'1),(yfx),(:))    .
```

Comment: you din't understand me i'm not looking to implement it in prolog i just want define facts and rules with the best data structure in python , so please re-read the post to get understand